# OpenStack installation - git pathspec Error

Tags: git, installation, ubuntu-14.04, openstack, openstack-swift

[I tried installing openstack-kilo stable version. What is the meaning of this Error? Is there any problem with my stack.sh file? Please Answer. Thanx in advance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXq6e.png)

Link for the screenshot of my terminal : Please Click on the Descreption.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Due to EOL of KILO(you can find release cycle details [here](http://releases.openstack.org/) they have removed the Kilo branch. I could not find the Kilo branch in github, [here](https://github.com/openstack/keystone/branches/all) is the list of git branch list

Though in Devstack Kilo branch is not removed [devstack github link](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/branches) your are still able to clone devstack with Kilo branch, however it fails while cloning keystone, as you have explicitly set branch to Kilo. You can try either setting liberty or the latest Mitaka, or the default master

Comment: Thank you Karthik. One of my Co-Developer told me that its better to use kilo than liberty because he thinks kilo has a good flexibility and support. I am working on  a project related to SWIFT. So is it ok to procede with liberty?

Comment: I believe it should be fine.